# Destination (port) unreachable freeswitch xlite

Tags: windows, ubuntu, firewall, freeswitch

ok so i have two machine on my LAN, one running Ubuntu 16.04 and the other Windows 10.

I installed and configured Freeswitch on the Linux one and installed X-Lite on the Windows one. What i'm trying to do is to register a SIP client using X-Lite on the Freeswitch server.

However each time i get the error message `problem at server (SIP error 408)`

The Wireshark entry on both machines gives this message

[image]

I configured the windows firewall to allow incoming connection on port 5060 and 5080 as freeswitch uses them, but still the same error!

can anyone help me?

Thanks

Comment: Make sure firewall/iptables at Ubuntu is allowing incoming connection from Xlite

Comment: i disable the firewall completely on the Linux machine. still no changes!

Comment: Try to paste `sofia status profile internal` in your question to help further

Comment: at last i cloned a server on which it was working and using it locally! i think there was a problem with the installation!